# changing roles in django app doesnt change the permissions

Tags: django

i'm building an app in django , where i have 2 types of users, "Creators" and "Subscribers"
A "Creator" should have access to all views, (add, change, view ..), Where a subscriber could only "view" the content.
The problem i have is when i create a subscriber for the first time, he only has permissions for subscribers, and when i edit his role from subscriber to creator, he can have access to creators persmissions, but when i change the role from creator to subscriber i still have creators permissions even if the current user is a Subscriber !

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    CREATOR = 'CREATOR'
    SUBSCRIBER = 'SUBSCRIBER'

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (CREATOR, 'Créateur'),
        (SUBSCRIBER, 'Abonné'),
    )
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photo de profil')
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, max_length=30, verbose_name='rôle')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.role == self.CREATOR:
            group = Group.objects.get(name='creators')
            group.user_set.add(self)
        elif self.role == self.SUBSCRIBER:
            group = Group.objects.get(name='subscribers')
            group.user_set.add(self)
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):

form = forms.UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
return render(request, 'authentication/upload_profile_photo.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'role']
```